# Read a csv into pandas that has commas *within* first/index cells of the csv rows without changing value

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Ok, I get this error...:
"pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 6 fields in line 12, saw 7"

...when trying to import a csv into a python script with pandas.read_csv():

```
path,Drawing_but_no_F5,Paralell_F5,Fixed,Needs_Attention,Errors
R:\13xx   Original Ranch Buildings\1301 Stonehouse\1301-015\F - Bid Documents and Contract Award,Yes,No,No,No,No
R:\13xx   Original Ranch Buildings\1302 Carriage House\1302-026A Carriage House, Redo North Side Landscape\F - Bid Document and Contract Award,Yes,No,No,No,No
R:\13xx   Original Ranch Buildings\1302 Carriage House\1302-028\F - Bid Documents and Contract Award,Yes,No,No,No,No
R:\13xx   Original Ranch Buildings\1302 Carriage House\1302-029\F - Bid Documents and Contract Award,Yes,No,No,No,No
```

Obviously, in the above entries, it is the third line that throws the error. Caveats include that I have to use that column as a path to process files there so changing the entry is not allowed. CSV is created elsewhere; I get it as-is.
I do want to preserve the column header.
This filepath column is used later as an index, so I would like to preserve that.

Many, **many** similar issues, but solutions seem very specific and I cannot get them to cooperate for my use case:

[Pandas, read CSV ignoring extra commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48668125/pandas-read-csv-ignoring-extra-commas)
Solutions seem to change entry values or rely on the cells being in the last column

[Commas within CSV Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123875/commas-within-csv-data)
Solution involves sql tools methinks. I don't want to read the csv into sql tables...
csv file is already delimited by commas so I don't think I changing the sep value will work.. (I cannot get it to work -- yet)

[Problems reading CSV file with commas and characters in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550441/problems-reading-csv-file-with-commas-and-characters-in-pandas)
Solution throws error: "for line in reader:_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)"
Not too optimistic since op had the cell value in quotes whereas I do not.

Comment: Turns out there is a parameter in pandas csv methods that resolves this: pandas.to_csv('filename.csv', quoting = 'QUOTE_NONNUMERIC')

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which is a minor modification of the accepted answer by @DSM in the last thread to which you linked ([Problems reading CSV file with commas and characters in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550441/problems-reading-csv-file-with-commas-and-characters-in-pandas)).

```
import csv

with open('original.csv', 'r') as infile, open('fixed.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for line in reader:
        newline = [','.join(line[:-5])] + line[-5:]
        writer.writerow(newline)
```

After running the above preprocessing code, you should be able to read `fixed.csv` using `pd.read_csv()`.

This solution depends on knowing how many of the rightmost columns are always formatted correctly. In your example data, the rightmost *five* columns are always good, so we treat everything to the *left* of these columns as a single field, which `csv.writer()` wraps in double quotes.

Comment: I can modify this to work. The for loop is indented too far. And the path column of rows with the 'extra' cell/comma are in quotes, whereas the others are not in quotes. I will probably want for them all to be in quotes if this is to be the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Whoops, edited the indentation. Glad this is helpful!

Comment: Turns out there is a parameter in pandas.read_csv() that does this